# Mongodb monitoring

Tags: mongodb, monitoring

I am using a mongodb in my application and i would like to ask if someone here has some tested tools to monitor the servers (similar to tools like heidi sql or mysql workbench). My main needs are processes monitoring and performance. However I'm quite new with mongo so if you can think of anything else thats worth monitoring, id be glad to hear about it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plan using mongostat and mongotop for quick and dirty analysis. For any charting requirements, you can use matplotlib (python libraries) to visualize log data

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However there is really no strong monitoring tool out there which can provide more than quick and dirty analysis? The best solution currently available is manually visualizing the graphs? Thank you very much

Comment: That's not entirely correct. If you are open for commercial solutions, you should check out MongoDB Cloud Manager

Comment: For non-production applications MongoDB Ops manager can be used for monitoring,  alerting and other Ops works.  You have to purchase license for Production clusters.  It's recently launched,  highly productive and complex tool.  Should be used carefully as it controls the complete cluster in a single click. However there are plenty of webinars available on MongoDB website with good documentation and best practices.